# Problems with perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I need a perl regex to match `A.CC3` on a line begining with something followed by anything then, my `'A.CC3 "` and then anything...

I am surprised this `(text =~ /^\W+\CC.*\A\.CC\[3].*/)` is not working

Thanks

Comment: the line should be something like this: //%CC Unused Static Globals, A.CC3, Halstead Progam Volume

Comment: You can add information to your question with the [`edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19494324/edit) button. You should not add vital information in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give this a shot:

`^.*?A\.CC.*$`

That will match anything until it reaches A, then a literal ., followed by CC, then anything until end of string.

Comment: Replacing `\W+\CC` with `.*?` might not be desired behaviour. And you still have `\A` in the middle of the string, so it will not match anything.

Comment: I didn't notice the \A, fixed now.

Comment: When not using captures or other special functionality, using anchors with optional wildcard strings is really not useful, unless you are attempting to exclude strings with newlines in them. This is really almost exactly the same as `A\.CC`.

Answer (score 4):

`\A` is an escape sequence that denotes beginning of line, or `^` like in the beginning of your regex. Remove the backslash to make it match a literal `A`.

Edit: You also seem to have `\C` in there. You should only use backslash to escape meta characters such as period `.`, or to create escape sequences, such as `\Q .. \E`.

At its simplest, a regex to match `A.CC3` would be

```
$text =~ /A\.CC3/
```

That's all you need. This will match any string with `A.CC3` in it. In the comments you mention the string you are matching is this:

```
my $text = "//%CC Unused Static Globals, A.CC3, Halstead Progam Volume";
```

You might want to avoid partial matches, in which case you can use word boundary `\b`

```
$text =~ /\bA\.CC3\b/
```

You might require that a line begins with `//%`

```
$text =~ m#^//%.*\bA\.CC3\b#
```

Of course, only you know which parts of the string should be matched and in what way. "Something followed by anything followed by A.CC3 followed by anything" really just needs the first simple regex.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you're trying to capture anything.  If that's the case, and all you need to do is find lines that contain `A.CC3` then you can simply do

```
if ( index( $str, 'A.CC3' ) >= 0 ) # Found it...
```

No need for a regex.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to match. If you want to pull back the whole line in which the A.CC3 pattern occurs then something like this should work:

```
^.*A\.CC3.*$
```